# extended class doesnt accept extended class type

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, polymorphism

In WolfStateController.Start() im trying to set State TrueState to WolfIdleState that inherits from State.

But WolfStateController extends StateController. Still its not accepted. Look at the Start method ive written the error message. Is this supposed to be possible? Either im missing something regarding polymorphism or my syntax is wrong.

```
    // STATECONTROLLER

public class StateController : MonoBehaviour 

{   
    public State<StateController> CurrentState;
}


public class WolfStateController : StateController
{
    void Start()
    {
        var idleState = new WolfIdleState();
        var keyPressDecision = new KeyPressedDecision(KeyCode.Space);

        // FOLLOWING GIVES ERROR: 
        // Cannot implicity convert WolfIdleState to State<StateController>
        keyPressDecision.TrueState = idleState; 
    }
}

// STATE

    public abstract class State<SC>  where SC : StateController 
    {
    }



   public abstract class WolfState : State<WolfStateController>
   {
   }



  public class WolfIdleState : WolfState 
   {
   }


    // DECISIONS

public abstract class StateDecision<SC> where SC : StateController
{

    public State<SC> TrueState;
}

public class KeyPressedDecision : StateDecision<StateController>
{

}
```

Comment: `State<WolfStateController>` is not the same thing as `State<StateController>`

Comment: That is correct. So I thought polymorphism would let me use wolfStateController because it extends StateController. No? Then what's the point with polymorphism?

Answer (score 2):

The error is correct. I think you need to check out the following article on covariance and contravariance.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

You could probably achieve what you want by using an interface.